# How Keep Running CountDownTimer After Restart Phone

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Im new in Android Programming.
I made count down timer and it works well. but i want to start again when phone is restart.
MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, PeriodDietService.class));
    }
```

PeriodDietService.java

```
public class PeriodDietService extends Service {
  CountDownTimer cdt = null;

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 3000) {
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Toast.makeText(PeriodDietService.this.getApplicationContext(), "Is Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(PeriodDietService.this.getApplicationContext(), "Is Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    };
    cdt.start();
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Tank you For Your Help

Answer (score 2):

You should use a BroadcaseReceiver that runs when the phone boots. You'd register this receiver in your manifest file with something like the below receiver tag, including whatever intents you want to trigger the receiver. In the onReceive method of the BroadcaseReceiver you can start your service (you may want to look at JobIntentService instead of service if you run into problems with background execution limits in later versions of android).

You'll want to consider how this behaves when starting up - should the countdown pick up where it left off, etc. It's possible you'll need a branch in your service that "resumes" the countdown, maybe saving your countdown progress at intervals and loading where you last left off.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.YourClassExtendingBroadCastReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```